# how to inline two border

Tags: html, css

this is my code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body, html, #app, .Main {
  height: 100%;
}
.Main {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.side-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 80px;
    align-items: center;

    margin: auto 0;
    height: 98%;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px -1.8px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.side-bar .icon {
    font-size: 40px;
}
.side-bar .icon:first-child {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 85%;
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.side-bar .icon:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.side-bar .icon:last-child {
    margin-top: auto;
}
.side-bar .active {
    color: rgb(0, 255, 170, 0.7);
}
.top-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 72.4px;
    justify-content: center;

    margin:0 auto;
    width: 95.1%;
    border-bottom: solid 2px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <div class="Main">
        <div style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
            <div class="side-bar">
                <i class="fad fa-home-alt icon"></i> 
                <i class="fad fa-th-large icon"></i>
                <i class="fad fa-keyboard icon"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-folder icon active"></i>
                <i class="fad fa-power-off icon"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="top-bar">
                <i class="side-bar fad fa-home-alt icon"></i> 
                <i class="side-bar fad fa-th-large icon"></i>
                <i class="side-bar fad fa-keyboard icon"></i>
                <i class="side-bar fas fa-folder icon active"></i>
                <i class="side-bar fad fa-power-off icon"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is what i spec to happen:

[image]

it's working but the problem is when i zoom in or out the borders width and position change, like this:

[image]

how can i change the borders width and position that when i zoom in or out the borders width and position does't change and get the same result as the first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `margin-top` to  `.side-bar .icon:first-child` :

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body, html, #app, .Main {
  height: 100%;
}
.Main {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.side-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 80px;
    align-items: center;

    margin: auto 0;
    height: 98%;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px -1.8px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.side-bar .icon {
    font-size: 40px;
}
.side-bar .icon:first-child {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 85%;
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.side-bar .icon:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.side-bar .icon:last-child {
    margin-top: auto;
}
.side-bar .active {
    color: rgb(0, 255, 170, 0.7);
}
.top-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 72.4px;
    justify-content: center;

    margin:0 auto;
    width: 95.1%;
    border-bottom: solid 2px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <div class="Main">
        <div style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
            <div class="side-bar">
                <i class="fad fa-home-alt icon"></i> 
                <i class="fad fa-th-large icon"></i>
                <i class="fad fa-keyboard icon"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-folder icon active"></i>
                <i class="fad fa-power-off icon"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="top-bar">
                <i class="side-bar fad fa-home-alt icon"></i> 
                <i class="side-bar fad fa-th-large icon"></i>
                <i class="side-bar fad fa-keyboard icon"></i>
                <i class="side-bar fas fa-folder icon active"></i>
                <i class="side-bar fad fa-power-off icon"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```